# Open links in browser using STTweetlabel

Tags: ios, twitter, browser, hyperlink, nsdictionary

I am using STTweetLabel to display tweets is a table view in my app.

The feed that i have contains links to websites e.g 'http://www.google.com'

What i am trying to do is, when the user touches a link within the tweet, it will open safari and direct them to whatever the link was.

Whats happening at the minute is, the link is auttomatically opened when it is displayed on in the tableview (without the user clicking it)

This is the code i have so far for detecting links:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *attributesLink;



- (NSDictionary *)attributesForHotWord:(STTweetHotWord)hotWord {
switch (hotWord) {
    case STTweetHandle:
        return _attributesHandle;
        break;
    case STTweetHashtag:
        return _attributesHashtag;
        break;
    case STTweetLink:




        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_attributesLink]];


        return _attributesLink;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

EDIT:

I also have this in my ViewController

```
        STTweetLabel *tweetLabel = [[STTweetLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 180.0)];


    tweetLabel.text.isAccessibilityElement = YES;




    [tweetLabel setText:text];
    tweetLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


    CGSize size = [tweetLabel suggestedFrameSizeToFitEntireStringConstraintedToWidth:tweetLabel.frame.size.width];
    CGRect frame = tweetLabel.frame;
    frame.size.height = size.height;
    tweetLabel.frame = frame;
    tweetLabel.textSelectable = YES;
    [tweetLabel setDetectionBlock:^(STTweetHotWord hotWord, NSString *string, NSString *protocol, NSRange range) {
        NSArray *hotWords = @[@"Handle", @"Hashtag", @"Link"];




        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Link"]];

        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [%d,%d]: %@%@", hotWords[hotWord], (int)range.location, (int)range.length, string, (protocol != nil) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@" *%@*", protocol] : @""];

    }];


    [cell addSubview:dateLabel];
    [cell addSubview:tweetLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue with the following:

```
    STTweetLabel *tweetLabel = [[STTweetLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0, 180.0)];


    tweetLabel.text.isAccessibilityElement = YES;

    [tweetLabel setText:text];
    tweetLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


    CGSize size = [tweetLabel suggestedFrameSizeToFitEntireStringConstraintedToWidth:tweetLabel.frame.size.width];
    CGRect frame = tweetLabel.frame;
    frame.size.height = size.height;
    tweetLabel.frame = frame;
    tweetLabel.textSelectable = YES;
    [tweetLabel setDetectionBlock:^(STTweetHotWord hotWord, NSString *string, NSString *protocol, NSRange range) {
        NSArray *hotWords = @[@"Handle", @"Hashtag", @"Link"];


        switch (hotWord) {
            case STTweetLink:

                //Open Safari with the link clicked
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]];


                break;

            case STTweetHashtag:

                //Preform acton when hashtag is clicked

                break;

            case STTweetHandle:

                //Preform action when username is clicked

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [%d,%d]: %@%@", hotWords[hotWord], (int)range.location, (int)range.length, string, (protocol != nil) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@" *%@*", protocol] : @""];

    }];


    [cell addSubview:dateLabel];
    [cell addSubview:tweetLabel];
}
```